# Playing Yahtzee on Matlab?

Tags: matlab, probability

Yatzi is a game played by rolling 5 dice. My function Yatzi simulates the rolling of 5 dice. The function should take one input, N umR olls, the total number of times that the 5 dice will be rolled. The function should have four outputs which give, in order, the relative frequencies (probabilities) of following scenarios:

- The 5 dice showing number 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5
- two, and only two, dice
- showing number 2  at least two dice showing number 4
- all 5 dice showing identical number

This is what I have so far, but I have no idea how to proceed. help please!

```
function Yatzi(np)

if nargin == 0
    np=1;
elseif ~(np>0 && real(np) && numel(np)==1)
    error('Invalid input for number of players.')
end


% set up initial points array
points = ones(13,np)*NaN;
% roll variable
roll = zeros(1,5);

    % initialize our rerolls variable
    rerolls = 1:5;


    for t = 1:3
        % throw the dice
        roll(rerolls) = randi(6,[1 length(rerolls)]);
    end
end
```

Comment: I think you should write out the logic of how you would go about solving this problem for yourself before you proceed with more code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can have a matrix of size  `5 x np` so you can store everything there in once. You don't have to use a `for` loop:

```
% throw the dice
roll(rerolls) = randi(6,[5 length(rerolls)]);
```

then you scan each column of the matrix and have a count value for each of the results you are looking for. In the end you divide with the total number of rolls to get the probability.

To check for each result you can have a number of `if` clauses. to make it more readable you can implement a function for example `checkForYahzee(result)` where result would be your roll column `roll(:,i)`

Each function can be checking for a different thing, for example:

```
if( result(1) == result(2) &&
 result(2) == result(3) &&
 result(3) == result(4) &&
 result(4) == result(5) )
% yahtzee!
end
```

You can find more clever ways to save comparisons etc